# Is research being done on interfaces that improve your health?

Tags: interaction-design, interface

I've been searching around for interfaces that improve your health but I'm not having much luck. I'm a software developer who's fed up with destroying my body by sitting stagnant in bad posture, slowly getting carpal tunnel and all the other side effects that go along with prolonged periods of sitting. Yes, there are stand up desks, but that's more of a bandaid solution IMO.

If anyone knows of any research being done or interfaces that exist that improve your health please let me know. By this I mean some way of interacting with computers that would improve or maintain the following:

- posture
- eyesight
- coordination
- circulation and cardiovascular health
- relieve stress
- increase energy
- speech

I don't expect something as drastic as a treadmill, but for example, why do we position our hands way in front of us and most of the time angled up, causing the blood to drain from our wrists and our shoulders to be forward. Shouldn't be have our arms down more so the blood can flow, and so our shoulders are down and back? Just off the top of my head.. but the point is we have to integrate our health into the design process. So far it seems to be totally void.

Answer (score 1):

[Ergonomics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_factors_and_ergonomics).

That's what you'll want to Google for, to find out all about it. Ergonomic keyboards, ergonomic desks, chairs, etc. So much research has been done, and so much will still be done in the future. It's huge.

And to run with your example: we sit like that because ergonomics research found that this is the ideal way. Sitting with your hands down, will cause blood to go there and stay there. When you take a long walk for example, you might find that your hands will start feeling all swollen!

For example, this image (to me) is a great example of what ergonomics has done for us:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I wont mark this as an answer just because I'm looking for a specific reference to an interface or to research which improves health beyond being ergonomic.

Comment: Yes, ergonomics of course helps, but anyone who works at a desk like this diagram shows will likely have issues with their low back, wrists, craning of the neck, etc. You hardly move at all when you interact with a computer in this way, so it doesn't improve your health. These kind of ergonomics merely lessen the impact on your health, but you still suffer.

Comment: Fair enough. That said, the image wasn't there to show the OP how to sit at his desk. It was there to illustrate what ergonomics research looks into.